# Is it possible to use an Alloy widget (like the Alloy Slider Menu) inside an non-Alloy project?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I have a Titanium app built in the old style with a lot of code already there.  It does not use any Alloy framework.  We want to convert from using tabs to using the facebook style slider menu.  I found a really good one here - http://www.danielsefton.com/2013/05/slider-menu-widget-v2-for-titanium-alloy/

But it is written using the Alloy framework.  Can I somehow use it in my app as a module or any other way?  If yes, can you please provide some sample code.  If no, what other options I may have other than converting my app to being an Alloy project.

Thanks so much for you help.  I have tried googling this but haven't found any answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you cant use alloy widget in non alloy project for making a titanium slider menu use this silder menu and you would be good to go

https://github.com/viezel/NappSlideMenu

Thanks